# WP Enqueue style on all plug-in pages

Tags: plugin-development, menus

i'm building a plugin and i want my enqueue style on all my pages not only the slug (toplevel

```
    function load_custom_wp_admin_style($hook) {
        if($hook != 'toplevel_page_myplugin') {
                return;
        }
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', plugins_url('css/style.css', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

This only gives me my style at the page admin.php?page=myplugin but i got more pages like admin.php?page=sieronline-page1 admin.php?page=myplugin-page2.

How can i do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you want enqueue style on all admin pages You can use the following code

```
    function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', plugins_url('css/style.css', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

Or if you want enqueue style on specific pages, You can use the following code

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style($hook) {
        if($hook != 'toplevel_page_myplugin' || $hook != 'widgets.php' || $hook != 'edit.php') {
                return;
        }
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', plugins_url('css/style.css', __FILE__) );
}
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```